# Can I set my Intranet to be able to send email with PHP?

Tags: php, email, iis-7

I am quite new to setting up servers. On my hosted external server I can use the mail() function in PHP to send email. I have a Windows 2008 server with IIS7 which I am using for an intranet. Mail() does not work on this server. From my research it appears that this is because the server is not connected to the internet, but this may be misinformation. Is there any way to get an email php function to work through this server? I have been unable to find a solution so far. I need this to work because I am using open source applications that require the ability to email.

Comment: mail() is unreliable use smtp

Comment: Can you explain exactly what that means/how to do that. I not know very much about this as of now.

Comment: Read below and try it, any questions ask

Answer (score 2):

Use SMTP. This protocol is used by basicly every mail provider to send mail.
Just for the simple part of it take a look at this tutorial: http://www.9lessons.info/2009/10/send-mail-using-smtp-and-php.html

You need an SMTP server, but your mail provider has one whether you have your own mail server or it is from your ISP

Comment: Thank you for your help. Which do you recommend between the two delivery methods, Deliver e-mail to SMTP server or Store e-mail in pickup directory.

Comment: Depents from what perspective, considering you use a script to send email i would advise SMTP server because it can filter if needed. Storing in a directory could generate unwanted crap and the only filter on that is the script.

Comment: I went with SMTP server and typed in 

`appcmd set config /commit:WEBROOT /section:smtp /from:string /deliveryMethod:network /network.port:int /network.defaultCredentials:True|False /network.host:string /network.userName:string /network.password:string` 

into the command prompt giving me the following error "'False' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Comment: Wait, what system, OS, service?

Comment: I am using Windows Server 2008 R2 with IIS7.

Comment: is this correct `/network.defaultCredentials:True|False`, should it not be either false or true. Not to mention but you didn't fill in anything. Did you install Server Core or Full server 2008 R2?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24908/discussion-between-s-lenders-and-user1324807)